# How to create a custom JIRA Agile report?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

Is it possible to create a Custom Report like Sprint or Epic report under Reports TAB in JIRA Agile?

If yes then how can I achieve the same? Is there any tutorial for it?

I am using **JIRA 6.1.7** version with **JIRA Agile plugin**.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- [jiraReports](https://www.jirareports.com/public/start), a cloud-based tool (supports Jira Agile)
- free-form reporting plugins like [eazyBI](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.eazybi.jira.plugins.eazybi-jira) or [Intelligent Reports](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.clariostechnology.intelligentreports) (both support Jira Agile)
- plugins for specific reports (search the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=jira&category=&cost=&hosting=&marketingLabel=&q=report))
- for complete customization, you can [create a plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Guide) using HTML and Java ([report-specific plugin tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+Report))